# How to schedule a job in every 4 hours in Autosys

Tags: autosys

I want to schedule a job in autosys in every 4 hours. Like this: 00:40, 04:40, 08:40, 12:40.
Could anyone help with with the JILL code syntax? I tried this It's failing.

start_times: "00:40, 4:40, 8:40, 12:40, 16:40"

days_of_week: "su,mo,tu,we,th,fr,sa"

date_conditions: "1"

Comment: As far as I know, this should works fine as the syntax is correct. Can you provide the error you get when importing your jil file ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
insert_job: job_name   job_type: BOX 
owner: owner@us
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: su,mo,tu,we,th,fr,sa
start_times: "00:40,04:40,08:40,12:40,16:40"
description: "test box"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
insert_job: job_name   job_type: c <br>
command: 'ls /abc/def/' <br>
machine: abc@def.com <br>
owner: owner@us <br>
date_conditions: 1 <br>
days_of_week: all <br>
start_times: "00:40,04:40,08:40,12:40,16:40" <br>
description: "test box" <br>
std_out_file: abc/def/success.log <br>
std_err_file: abc/def/error.log <br>
```